# Weird spacing problem with a font - Indesign

Tags: fonts, adobe-indesign

I am using a font (custom made)for a title- which never posed any problem in other programs (illustrator, powerpoint, etc) - and it is acting very odly. See for yourself:
[image]

It gives me this huge space above it. And it doesn't do that when I change the font...

I am very confused :-s

Comment: Have you checked the paragraph settings; for line-height?

Comment: Leading, line-height, baseline snapping, text frame alignment... it could be any number of things.

Comment: What font is that? I've had some fonts act weird in specific cases. Bad baselines and such..

Answer (score 1):

Might be an "UFO (Undefined Frustrating Object)" problem.

If any of above suggestions didn't solve your problem you should check 'Text Frame Options' Ctrl(Cmd)+b. Thick the 'Ignore Text Wrap' option. If you gonna make it, means that you have some object (empty frame, background image etc.) with 'Text Wrap' option set to on.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have superscript accidentally selected. I've had this issue before.

Answer (score 0):

If simply changing the font fixes your problem, it's a metrics problem associated with that font alone. A few things may be causing this:

- **Corrupted font file.** Try wiping and reinstalling a fresh copy. If you created this font yourself, you might even try a fresh export.
- **Corrupted InDesign doc.** Create a fresh doc and try it there (probably not news to you).
- **Bad metrics in your font.** I'd put my money on this one. You said that it's a custom font. Not every app reads the metrics the same. InDesign is very much about typography and there's a good chance it's seeing something other apps do not.